# Gsuite SMTP emails not being sent

Tags: smtp, google-workspace

I've successfully connected my django server to G suite to make use of the smtp routing service. When a user signs up for an account on my page
- the email ends up in my sent folder within my admin account, which is registered on Gsuite
- the email doesn't actually get delivered to the person who signed up

Any thoughts on what might be the cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some emails have trickled through. Looks like Gsuite needs 24 hours for propagation before becoming fully functional.

Comment: Can you clarify what you said? Do you mean you created a new G Suite account, and it took 24 hours to become functional?

Comment: correct. as per G suite support, it takes this long before messages start sending quickly.

Comment: Thank you. I have set up G Suite many times, but I ignored setup time. For me, the total time was in tens of minutes. No significant delay that I noticed.